# Sharepoint 2013 - Possible to drop and drag an attachment to a custom list?

Tags: drag-and-drop, sharepoint-2013, attachment

In Sharepoint 2013, I know it's possible to drop and drag a file to a document library, but is it possible to drop and drag a file (text, jpg, pdf, etc.) to a list, as an attachment? If so, how?

For example, if I have user submitting a Service Request (NewForm.aspx), and they have a screenshot of an error message saved as a jpg, I would want them to be able to drop and drag the jpg file to the form, to the Attachment field. Of course they could "browse" to it using the existing attachment functionality, but just interested to know if the form would allow dropping and dragging of attachments.

Thanks,
George